# The type cannot be used as type parameter in the generic type or method

Tags: c#, generics

I have a DBHelper class from which I fire callbacks to convert IDataReader to a Generic Type. I have got the entire code up and running. However, I run into trouble when I attempt to create an instance of the type within the callback, with the where clause applied [See -> DataReaderToResultItemConverterCallback in class TestOneCallbacks].

The where clause makes it perfect. TResult will be type **TestOne**ResultItem. But, I am unable to make this work with the where clause. Alternatively, directly creating **TestTwo**ResultItem [See -> class TestTwoCallbacks] and casting makes it work, but not elegant.

This is the following Error for TestOneCallbacks,

> The type 'TResult' cannot be used as type parameter 'TResult' in the
>   generic type or method
>   'DataAccess.TestOneCallbacks.DataReaderToResultItemConverterCallback(System.Data.IDataReader)'.
>   There is no boxing conversion or type parameter conversion from
>   'TResult' to 'Service.Interface.TestFilterResultItem'.

Here is the code.

```
public static class DBHelper
{
    public static List<TResult> ExecuteQuery<TResult>(DataQueryArgs<TResult> dataQueryArgs)
    {
        List<TResult> result = null;
        {
            IDataReader reader = null;

            //Get the input parameters for the query
            Dictionary<string, object> inputParameters = dataQueryArgs.InputParameters;

            //Fire callback to Get the DbCommand for the query
            DbCommand command = dataQueryArgs.GetCommandCallback();

            //Fire callback to Get the list of Sql input Parameters for the query
            List<SqlParameter> sqlParameters = dataQueryArgs.CreateSQLParametersCallback(inputParameters);

            //Execute the query and get an IDataReader object
            reader = ExecuteQuery(command, sqlParameters);

            //Fire callback Convert the IReader to ResultItem
            result = dataQueryArgs.DataReaderToResultItemConverterCallback(reader);
        }

        return result;
    }

    private static IDataReader ExecuteQuery(DbCommand command, List<SqlParameter> sqlParameters)
    {
        IDataReader reader = null;
        {
            //TODO:
        }

        return reader;
    }
}

class TestOneResultItem
{
    public TestOneResultItem()
    {
    }

    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
    public DateTime DOB { get; set; }
}

class TestTwoResultItem
{
    public TestTwoResultItem()
    {
    }

    public string Description { get; set; }
    public int Size { get; set; }
}

public class TestOneCallbacks
{
    public DataQueryArgs<TResult> InitializeDataQueryCallbacks<TResult>(Dictionary<string, object> dataQueryArgs_inputParameters)
    {
        DataQueryArgs<TResult> args = null;
        DataQueryArgs<TResult>.DataReaderToResultItemConverter<TResult> dataReaderToResultItemConverterCallback = this.DataReaderToResultItemConverterCallback<TResult>;
        args = new DataQueryArgs<TResult>(dataReaderToResultItemConverterCallback);

        return args;
    }

    public List<TResult> DataReaderToResultItemConverterCallback<TResult>(IDataReader reader) where TResult : TestOneResultItem
    {
        List<TResult> results = new List<TResult>();
        TResult t1 = new TResult();     //Activator.CreateInstance ???
        {
            t1.Name = "ShaQ";
            t1.Age = 99;
            t1.DOB = DateTime.Now;
        }
        results.Add(t1);
        return results;
    }
}

public class TestTwoCallbacks
{
    public DataQueryArgs<TResult> InitializeDataQueryCallbacks<TResult>(Dictionary<string, object> dataQueryArgs_inputParameters)
    {
        DataQueryArgs<TResult> args = null;
        DataQueryArgs<TResult>.DataReaderToResultItemConverter<TResult> dataReaderToResultItemConverterCallback = this.DataReaderToResultItemConverterCallback<TResult>;
        args = new DataQueryArgs<TResult>(dataReaderToResultItemConverterCallback);

        return args;
    }

    public List<TResult> DataReaderToResultItemConverterCallback<TResult>(IDataReader reader) where TResult : TestTwoResultItem
    {
        var results = new List<TestTwoResultItem>();
        TestTwoResultItem t1 = new TestTwoResultItem();     //Activator.CreateInstance ???
        {
            t1.Description = "This works...";
            t1.Size = 345;
        }
        results.Add(t1);
        return results as List<TestTwoResultItem>;      //Ugly, but I know exactly what I am doing. This cast will succeed!
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are passing `TResult` to that method, the `TResult` you derive from the calling method should have the same type constraint as the called method. So you have to add the type constraint `where TResult : TestOneResultItem` to the calling method: `InitializeDataQueryCallbacks`.

```
public DataQueryArgs<TResult> InitializeDataQueryCallbacks<TResult>
       (Dictionary<string, object> dataQueryArgs_inputParameters)
       where TResult : TestOneResultItem
```

And by the way, in order to call the `TResult` constructor, you need the `new()` constraint:

```
       where TResult : TestOneResultItem, new()
```

Comment: That worked for that method, but the calling method of InitializeDataQueryCallbacks() started throwing the same error. As I walk up that chain, I come across calls in an Inheritance hierarchy. It is the call to this 'interface' that creates the necessary specific type from the inheritance tree and makes the calls based on a specific type of TResult (TestOneResultItem/TestTwoResultItem). The TResult has a 1-1 relation with the specific type from this inheritance tree.

Comment: While it didn't exactly solve my problem, it helped me to achieve what I needed. So will accept this.